# Declaration Site Variance in Java

Tags: java

All the articles (Medium/ChatGPT/StackOverflow) that I have read say "Java does not have declaration-site variance like some other programming languages such as Kotlin or Scala". But when I try it, I am able to create a class where I declare variance in class signature rather than at time of usage

```
static class FruitCrate<T extends Fruit> {
        private final List<T> items = new ArrayList<>();

        public T produce() {
            return items.get(0);
        }

        public void consume(T item) {
            items.set(1, item);
        }

        public int size() {
            return items.size();
        }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This unimplemented proposal to add declaration-site variance to Java gives a good overview https://openjdk.org/jeps/300

Comment: What the example in the question shows is not declaring variance, but a [bounded type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Comment: And none of this has anything to do with the [tag:variance] tag, which is about statistical variance.